# Cassandra : Oracle rownum

Tags: cassandra, rownum

Does cassandra has a feature of ROWNUM which allow to run a select statement to select the row by row number instead of value in the column?

One of the link from Oracle Ask Tom on ROWNUM. 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

No. Cassandra does not have this feature.

You need row key to retrive row from column family, Same as we need key to retrive value from HashMap in Java. While columns are sorted and you can retrive column by range or column name.